# Breakpoint that stops if statement would throw an exception

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

Switching from Eclipse I'm wondering if there is a possibility in IDEA to make a breakpoint that only stops if the statement on its line would throw an exception.

To achieve this in Eclipse I copy the statement into the breakpoint condition and add `; return false;`. Eclipse then stops if there's an exception thrown while evaluating the breakpoint condition.

In IDEA however the condition has to be an expression. When I tried to add a semicolon, IDEA always stated the expression was invalid.

How can I achieve a similar behavior to the one I have in Eclipse or how do you work around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I handle such situations by surrounding the statement with a `try/catch` clause and putting the breakpoint in the catch block. It requires to recompile your code though.

Comment: If there's no other way, this is probably the best solution.

Comment: It's not what I hoped for but the functionality I'm looking for doesn't seem to exist in IDEA. I'm going to use this technique and therefore marked this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij IDEA you can create something called `Exception breakpoints`. Maybe it will fulfill your requirements. Exact procedure is described [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/creating-exception-breakpoints.html).

You could combine it with standard `Line breakpoint`. For example you could add a `Line Breakpoint` on the line of the statement and use an option `Disabled until selected breakpoint is hit` and point there at the `Exception Breakpoint` activated by required exception class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I already saw this option. If it was possible to restrict an exception breakpoint to a specific line, it would do what I want.

Comment: Can you elaborate your addition further? I tried many combinations but was only able to have it stop always or never. Even if it would stop, it probably would when the exception already happened. I'm trying to stop before the exception.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right, this solutions only stops when the exception is already thrown.

Comment: However, maybe this will be useful to you: [chronon debugger](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/try-chronon-debugger-with-intellij-idea-13-1-eap/)